# python bs4 find data in class

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Good day

Please how do I write all the data in

```
                <tr class="t1">
                <th>Th
                    27. 02. 2020</th>
                <td>
                    19:00</td>
                <td>Záskok</td>
                <td class="center">0</td>
                <td>
```

my code is

for tr in soup.find_all("tr", class_="t1"):

```
date = soup.find("th").text
name = soup.find("td", text="Záskok").text
number = soup.find("td", text="Záskok").find_next_sibling("td").text


print(date, ":",name, ":", number)
```

Comment: Are you facing any error in your current code ? If so, where ?

Comment: @Gary
code is: 
`for td in soup.find_all("td", text=hra):
 
 datum = soup.find("th").text
 jmeno = soup.find("td", text=hra).text
 pocet = soup.find("td", text=hra).find_next_sibling("td").text


 print(datum, ":",jmeno, ":", pocet)`
output:
Datum : Maškaráda : 14
Datum : Maškaráda : 14
Datum : Maškaráda : 14